# array<double*> to vector<double> range v3 style on VS2019

Tags: c++17, range-v3

I want to convert an `array<double*>` to a `vector<double>` so that I can do a `ranges::views::concat` on two vectors of the same type but I'm having difficulty doing this.

I have the following code:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

#include <array>

static constexpr auto max_elements = 2000;

struct PriceInfo
{
    std::array<double*, max_elements> prices;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    const PriceInfo* const buf_prices = nullptr;
    const auto vec = buf_prices->prices 
                   | ranges::views::indirect 
                   | ranges::to_vector;
}
```

When I compile I'm getting the following errors and I don't understand why as I believe my code is correct, at least it compiles errorfree under gcc.

Error (active)  E0349   no operator "|" matches these operands
[image]

How do I fix this error please?

Comment: First of all, you are dereferencing a `nullptr` here (`buf_prices`). This is UB.

Comment: nullptr is there as a place marker and test. Assume a correctly formed array of pointers.

Comment: Here's a godbolt play area: https://godbolt.org/z/MezYh1

Comment: Here's another with a proper array initialisation : https://godbolt.org/z/3G1oTT

Comment: @Andrew it's still ub... you dereference non-volatile nullptr and write to non-existing object. Compiler allowed to skip that or do whatever

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of, your code contains UB, because you had never created PriceInfo.
Second, the error may mean incorrect project configuration, is standard set? is compiler fully compatible with requirements of library? Is it proper fork of library, if that's the case (e.g. there were separate forks for MSVC compilers).
Third, assuming those problems will be solved, this code would segfault unless ALL elements of prices are non-nullptr.

This way it works:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

static constexpr auto max_elements = 3; //  will segfault if there are null pointers

struct PriceInfo
{
    std::array<double*, max_elements> prices;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    auto a = std::array<double,3>{1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
    const PriceInfo* const buf = new PriceInfo{&a[0],  &a[1],  &a[2]};
    
    const auto vec = buf->prices 
                   | ranges::views::indirect 
                   | ranges::to_vector;
                   
    for( auto a : vec)
        std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Here's a godbolt of your code and it fails on msvc2019: https://godbolt.org/z/jbczf8

Comment: @Andrew It succeeds after changing "views" to "view" (https://godbolt.org/z/xaMqj9). The MSVC Compiler Explorer VMs seem to be using an ancient version of range-v3.

Comment: @casey it's using the vcpkg install, I'm using the same so I assume I have the same problem. Thanks for your help.